# Is there an app that will list my phone's info in an easily copy/paste-able format?

Tags: applications, system-info

There's a great Add-on for Firefox called [InfoLister](http://mozilla.doslash.org/infolister/), all it does is provide a nicely formatted list of stuff and versions, for example here's what it lists for me:

> Last updated: Thu, 27 Jan 2011
>   17:03:32 GMT
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203
>   Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729;
>   .NET4.0E)
>
> Extensions (enabled: 23, disabled: 7):
>
> - Contacts 0.3.2
> - DOM Inspector 2.0.8
> - etc...
>
> Themes (1):
>
> - Default 3.6.13 [selected]
>
> Plugins (13):
>
> - Garmin Communicator Plug-In
> - Google Talk Plugin
> - etc...

Are there any Android apps that can generate an easily copy & paste-able list of the phone's version, etc. all in one place? Basically the stuff that appears in Settings -› About phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also wrote an app in response to this question. It's free in the market. Let me know what you think. If you want more information, please let me know and I'll add what I can.

It's called "[Android Information Text](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.reassembler.textinfo) ".

Comment: Looks good, am impressed that one question on here got two different devs writing apps to solve the problem! You can find Reassembler's at http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-information-text/org.reassembler.textinfo

Answer (score 8):

Well out of my own curiosity, I made this to start:

https://github.com/dieseltravis/AndroidBuildInfo

[image: emulator]

Here it is running on my Moto Flipside:

[image: moto-flipside]

Comment: Upvoted for developer initiative!

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course

SysHard Info - show system and hardware information on Android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kinocat.andinfo

[Copy Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRfoK.png)

Comment: What is your connection to this software? Are you the developer? It seems to be relatively new, so maybe you could share the qualities that meet the requirements of the question?

Comment: Who are you and what you want from me?

Comment: This stackexchange likes developers to reveal their connection to software they have created to resolve the question. The company name of this tool is similar to your username, and it is a recent build. Is there a connection? If so, you should be clear about that.

Comment: Can you only copy the info out of the Pro version?

Comment: @wbogacz: Indeed:  "ua" is the ISO country code for Ukraine; and "Andrey" is probably the Ukrainian variant of the English name "Andrew".

Comment: In case you wonder why, [how to not be a spammer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) explains it: "*Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you **must** disclose your affiliation in your answers.*". As of current writing, it's unclear if this is an attempt to promote your app particularly or not. Is there a reason why you don't want to disclose it?