# Free system information for Android such as Everest for Windows

Tags: hardware, system, system-info

There is any apk that shows the system and hardware information about my Adroid phone??? I mean an aplication such as Everest (or msinfo32) does for Windows.

Comment: See also this older, and more specific, question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/is-there-an-app-that-will-list-my-phones-info-in-an-easily-copy-paste-able-forma

Comment: SysHard Info - show system and hardware information on Android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kinocat.andinfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quadrant](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard) also give me the same information that Android System Info.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Android system Info](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&feature=order_history).

You will me amazed how much information this application provides.

Answer (score 3):

[Elixir](http://www.appbrain.com/app/elixir/bt.android.elixir) is one of the most widely downloaded comprehensive system info app for android.

Answer (score 2):

Quick System Info is what I use (and was preinstalled in my LeeDroid ROM)